# Cant deploy Spring Boot application. Error 404 on any page

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

I have problem, i make Spring Boot app and i have bigger problem with deploy it than write it. 
So, when i start my app manualy from IDE STS, app work fine, but when i pack it to .jar and try run it from CMD with command java -jar appname.jar . Application run but when i want to visit any page, i get error 404.

I think it is some problem with package process. When i run project from cmd and i try to enter on any site ( http : //localhost:8080/answers for example) in CMD i get new line with SQL request... so Controllers are ok, application cant see .jsp files. 
in `application.properties` i have :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/

spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

I have all needed dependencies in my POM : `[https://pastebin.com/c0hqwYT8][1]`

My application.class is like tutorials : `[https://pastebin.com/yHscwEm0][1]`

My project structure :  `[http://imgur.com/a/LEciD][1]` `[http://imgur.com/a/LvaWc][1]`

Comment: try to add to your application.properties
`server.context-path="mypath"`
and then access it from \mypath

Comment: If you are building a web application containing pages then the file should be a `war` file.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala Not neccessary, it could be executable jar(for spring boot)

Comment: its looks like jar file ddont have jsp files ... i have folders like BOOT-INF META-INF org 
in boot-inf i have classes and lib 
in meta-inf  i havve folder maven with POM  and manifest

Answer (score 1):

I HAVE IT ! 
I must put my views to /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/ Path like in this tutorial : https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1