# Spring boot JSF executable JAR can not find xhtml files

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jsf, xhtml, executable-jar

I have the problem that my spring boot JSF application works in IntelliJ but not as an executable JAR. The application starts up without a problem, but it can not resolve the xhtml templates. In IntelliJ everything works as expected.

I found this question regarding a similar problem. I oriented at the file structure and can not see any difference.

[Spring Boot JSF packaging as a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461109/spring-boot-jsf-packaging-as-a-jar)

My maven file structure:

```
  src
   | main
      | resources
           | META-INF
               | resources
                    | index.xhtml
               | faces-config.xml
```

So when I start the Spring Boot application it will pick up at target/classes

The structure there is:

```
 target
   | classes
        | META-INF
             | resources
                  | index.xhtml
             | faces-config.xml
```

In the created executable JAR the structure is

```
  org
  BOOT-INF
     | lib
     | classes
         | de ...
  META-INF
     | resources
         | index.xhtml
     | faces-config.xml
```

As far as I understand various sites and answers, this should be the correct structure in the jar to pick up the xhtml files. But it does not work for me. I copied out of desperation the META-INF directory into the BOOT-INF/classes directory and in another iteration just the resources directory from META-INFO into BOOT-INF/classes. But nothing works. It can still not resolve the xhtml files.

How should be the structure of my jar file?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with packaging JSF pages to executable jar. There are other  SO topics (aren't helpful for me) related to the issue:

- [Cant deploy Spring Boot application. Error 404 on any page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593679/cant-deploy-spring-boot-application-error-404-on-any-page)
- [Springboot Whitelabel Error Page with JSF (AWS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454137/springboot-whitelabel-error-page-with-jsf-aws)

I ended up converting the project to *war*.
Hopefully [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/) supports executable wars.

1. I specified `<packaging>war</packaging>` in pom.xml.
2. I had to remove `<layers><enabled>true</enabled></layers>` from spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration.

War project structure:

```
 pom.xml
 src
 └── main
     ├── java
     │   └── xxx
     ├── resources
     │   ├── application.yml
     └── webapp
         ├── xxx.xhtml
         └── WEB-INF
             └── faces-config.xml
```

spring-boot-maven-plugin runs its `repackage`. Unzipped war structure:

```
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── maven
│       └── com.fusion
│           └── jsf-application
│               ├── pom.properties
│               └── pom.xml
├── org
│   └── springframework
│       └── boot
│           └── loader
│               ... spring classes here
│               └── WarLauncher.class
├── xxx.xhtml
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ... project classes 
    ├── faces-config.xml
    └── lib
        ... all the libs
```

It's possible to run the *war* using `java -jar jsf-application.war`.

Comment: Excellent answer! I have spent days investigating this and ended up at exactly this.
However, it would be nice if xxx.xhtml files could be placed under WEB-INF as well. This is possible for jsp files with application.properties:
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/
But for JSF files (xxx.xhtml) it does not seem to work...

Comment: Kindly share a working sample for spring boot 2+JSF2 with WAR deployment option. I am getting errors like javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: locale="#{languageBean.getLanguage()}" Attribute did not evaluate to a String or Locale: null....Seems @ManagedBean are not be recognized or loaded. Any idea why?